Is this graph a Hamiltonian graph

I can try various different paths to see if one works but only to find a Hamiltonian path instead of a Hamiltonian circle.
I tried some properties of a Hamiltonian graph should have but failed.
My question is:How can we prove the graph above is a Hamiltonian graph or not a Hamiltonian graph?And is there any references about this graph?
Thank you!

Some definations: A simple path in a graph G that passes through every
vertex exactly once is called a Hamilton  path, and a simple circuit
in a graph G that passes through every vertex exactly once is called
a Hamilton circuit


With only 7 vertices, brute force should be possible.

Please describe the Hamiltonian path, thank you.

A hamiltonian cycle must visit the 3 most outer vertices, hence it must contain the 6 edges that are adjacent to these vertices. Hence it contains 3 edges that end at the central vertex. This is impossible, hence the graph is not hamiltonian.

It's not. Checked with this Sage code
g1 = graphs.ClawGraph()
g2 = graphs.CycleGraph(3)
g = Graph()
for e in g1.edges():
    g.add_edge((0,e[0]), (0,e[1]))
for e in g2.edges():
    g.add_edge((1,e[0]), (1,e[1]))

for k in range(3):
    g.add_edge((0,0), (1,k)) #middle connected to all of c3
    g.add_edge((0,k+1), (1,k)) #claw to vertex

show(g)
print (g.is_hamiltonian()) #False


Mathematica:
g = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
    2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
    2 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
    3 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 
    3 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
    2 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 7},
   VertexLabels -> "Name"];
HamiltonianGraphQ[g]

False
